# (Video-JS) Error from one video prevents all other videos from playing

Tags: javascript, flash, html5-video, video.js

I'm implementing [Video-JS](http://www.videojs.com/) in to a client's website. The player works perfectly if the source of the video is found (of course). However, when the source of the video is not found, the plugin throws a JS error in the console:
`VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) FLASH: srcnotfound`.

Such behavior is expected in this circumstance. However, that single error prevents all other Video-JS dependent videos from being playable.

I would prefer that the rest of the videos in the video gallery work correctly in the unlikely event that a video source is not found.

Is it possible to disable or catch the error and handle it in a manner that does not affect the rest of the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that this problem isn't related to the source not being found at all. Each video-js video must have a unique `id` attribute in the `<video>` tag in order for the flash videos to work.